# Sitecore EXM 3.2(ECM) Assign goal to the triggered message

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-ecm, sitecore-exm

I need to do a simple newsletter form. This form should work like this:

- User inputs an email and presses to the submit button
- User recieves message on email with confirm link
- After user clicks on the link his email is added to Recipient list

This form should be work with help EXM

I've created Triggered message in the EXM with link for subscription. 
And I wrote this code for the Submit button for trigger the Newsletter Goal

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewsletterSubscribe(NewsletterViewBag model)
    {

        var goal = Context.Database.GetItem(newsletterGoal);

        if (goal == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var registerGoal = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PageEventItem(goal);

        var eventData = Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(registerGoal);

        eventData.Data = goal[DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)];

        Tracker.Submit();

    }
```

How I can assign my triggered message to the newsletterGoal?
Also I try manually send message this way:

```
 MessageItem message = Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Factory.GetMessage(new ID(messageId));
   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.AsyncSendingManager manager = new AsyncSendingManager(message);
   var contactId = ClientApi.GetAnonymousIdFromEmail(email);
   var recipientId = (RecipientId) new XdbContactId(contactId);
   manager.SendStandardMessage(recipientId);
```

And I see error in the log: The recipient 'xdb:857bbea1-1f18-4621-a798-178399cd0b54' does not exist. But Triggered Message haven't any recipient list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goals are not assigned directly to messages. You can, however, assign engagement plans and campaigns. Each message has its own engagement plan to handle tracking the contacts actions with the message. If you create a campaign that triggers a goal, you can assign that to the message and it will be associated with the contact when they receive the message. You can also leverage the message engagement plan to trigger events as the contact proceeds through those states.

Also, you're missing some details while recording the contact data.
Look at the newsletter signup control that is included in the EXM module. The important part in there is this:

```
    protected virtual RecipientId RecipientId
    {
        get
        {
            RecipientId recipientId = null;

            var contactId = ContactId;

            if (contactId != (ID)null)
            {
                recipientId = new XdbContactId(contactId);
            }

            return recipientId;
        }
    }

    protected virtual ID ContactId
    {
        get
        {
            if (!Email.Visible || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Text))
            {
                return new ID(Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
            }

            var anonymousId = ClientApi.GetAnonymousIdFromEmail(Email.Text);

            return anonymousId.HasValue ? new ID(anonymousId.Value) : new ID(Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void UpdateEmailInXdb()
    {
        _recipientRepository.UpdateRecipientEmail(RecipientId, Email.Text);
    }
```

It will write the email address directly to Mongo, rather than waiting for the session to end. Include this and the related RecipientId and ContactId properties in your signup code.

Once they are signed up you can register the goal programmatically or send them to a Thank You page where the goal can be registered (Advanced - Tracking), or send the message and let that register the goal. Or create an engagement plan with states for each step of the process (this is the best way).

You'll also want to add the recipient to a list that the newsletter message can use later. Actually, it looks to me like the example Subscription Form does everything you need.

Comment: But I haven't even sent a message. I thought that it would work like this:
1. user clicks on the submit button
2. I process it and register some goal
3. EXM catch that goal was registered and send Triggered message to the email which user inputed in newsletter form

Comment: It looks like the example Subscription Form does everything you need. I would recommend building an Engagement Plan and creating a Campaign and additional goals to handle moving the contact through the flow. Triggered messages can be send as an Action in an Engagement Plan. This way all your signup code needs to do is save the contact info. The rest can be done with page analytics and a campaign and some goals. Feel free to pm me and we can talk more detail.

Comment: Sitecore EXM 3.2 Out of the Box (OOTP) Subscription form does not work. You need to write this code manually. This is fixed in EXM 3.3 initial release which requires Sitecore 8.1 update 3.                                                                https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email%20Experience%20Manager/Email%20Experience%20Manager%2033/Email%20Experience%20Manager%2033%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes